# ServiceModel.Discovery.DiscoveryClient(string endpointConfigurationName) throws ArgumentNullException

Tags: c#, wcf, discovery

I have a small WCF Client which I'm trying to configure for service discovery via the application configuration file - however whenever I do this:

```
// Create a new DiscoveryClient instance from the 'DiscoveryEndpoint'
// configuration in App.config
DiscoveryClient discoveryClient = new DiscoveryClient("DiscoveryEndpoint");
```

I get an `ArgumentNullException`, `Value cannot be null.  Parameter name: contract`.  There is no `contract` parameter for this overload of the `DiscoveryClient` constructor, and the contract is correctly specified in the App.config (see below).

Here are the relevant sections of the App.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <client>
    <endpoint name="DiscoveryEndpoint"
              contract="IExampleContract"
              kind="dynamicEndpoint"
              endpointConfiguration="DynamicEndpointConfiguration"/>
  </client>

  <standardEndpoints>
    <dynamicEndpoint>
      <standardEndpoint name="DynamicEndpointConfiguration">
        <discoveryClientSettings>
          <endpoint kind="udpDiscoveryEndpoint"/>
          <findCriteria duration="00:00:02">
            <types>
              <add name="IExampleContract"/>
            </types>
            <scopes>
              <add scope="urn://wcf.test.com/examples/exampleContract/development"/>
            </scopes>
          </findCriteria>
        </discoveryClientSettings>
      </standardEndpoint>
    </dynamicEndpoint>
  </standardEndpoints>
</system.serviceModel>
```

This is targetted at .NET Framework 4.0, using Visual Studio 2010 SP1.

The documentation for this overload of the [DiscoveryClient(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd269778%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) constructor indicates that this should create a new `DiscoveryClient` instance with the configuration identified in App.config.

Has anyone else encountered this behaviour, and if so how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

The "DiscoveryEndpoint" that you defined in the config file is actually a service client end point, not the DiscoveryClient end point.

The following should work:

```
var exampleContractChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IExampleContract>("DiscoveryEndpoint");
var exampleContractClient = exampleContractChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
// You can now invoke methods on the exampleContractClient
// The actual service endpoint used by the client will be looked up dynamically 
// by the proxy using the DiscoveryClient class internally.
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've spent a lot of time in the debugger with the `Enable .NET Framework source stepping` option enabled, and I've found that the cause of this exception being thrown is (probably) a bug in the implementation of the way that the `DiscoveryClient` is instantiated from the configuration file - there is a call way down the call stack which passes a hard-coded value of `null` into a `contract` parameter, which is where the originating exception is thrown.

So, after much head-scratching, and lots of searching, I've come up with the following workaround (well, more like a total `HACK:`!) - which I'm posting here to help out anyone else who might encounter the same issue.

```
// HACK: The following is a workaround for a bug in .NET Framework 4.0
//       Discovery should be possible when setup from the App.config with the
//       following three lines of code:
//
//         discoveryClient = new DiscoveryClient("DiscoveryEndpoint");
//         Collection<EndpointDiscoveryMetadata> serviceCollection = discoveryClient.Find(new FindCriteria(typeof(IExampleContract))).Endpoints;
//         discoveryClient.Close();
//
//       However, a bug in the Discovery Client implementation results in an
//       ArgumentNullException when running discovery in this way.
//
//       The following code overcomes this limitation by manually parsing the
//       standard WCF configuration sections of App.config, and then configuring
//       the appropriate FindCriteria for a programmatically configured discovery
//       cycle.  This code can be replaced by the above three lines when either
//         1. The bug in .NET Framework 4.0 is resolved (unlikely), or
//         2. The application is retargeted to .NET Framework 4.5 / 4.5.1
//
//       To aid future developers, this HACK will be extensively documented

// Load the App.config file into a ConfigurationManager instance and load the configuration
Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

// Get the ServiceModel configuration group
ServiceModelSectionGroup serviceModelGroup = ServiceModelSectionGroup.GetSectionGroup(configuration);

// Get the StandardEndpoints configuration node
StandardEndpointsSection section = serviceModelGroup.StandardEndpoints;

// Get the DynamicEndpoint configuration node
Configuration dynamicEndpointConfiguration = section["dynamicEndpoint"].CurrentConfiguration;

// Get the first DynamicEndpoint configuration
// HACK: This assumes only one DynamicEndpoint configuration exists
//       No additional configurations will be interpreted.  This should
//       not pose a problem as typically a client will only access a
//       single service instance.  This can be extended if necessary
//       at a later time.
DynamicEndpointElement element = ((DynamicEndpointElement)serviceModelGroup.StandardEndpoints["dynamicEndpoint"].ConfiguredEndpoints[0]);

// Set the required Contract Type
// HACK: This is currently hard-coded to prevent the need to specify
//       an AssemblyQualifiedName in the App.config file.  This will
//       not typically pose a problem as each client will typically
//       only open a single service exposing a single, well-known,
//       Contract Type
FindCriteria criteria = new FindCriteria(typeof(IExampleContract));

// Add all required Scopes to the FindCriteria instance
foreach (ScopeElement scopeElement in element.DiscoveryClientSettings.FindCriteria.Scopes)
{
    criteria.Scopes.Add(scopeElement.Scope);
}

// Get the Discovery Duration
criteria.Duration = element.DiscoveryClientSettings.FindCriteria.Duration;

// Create a new Discovery Client instance
DiscoveryClient discoveryClient = new DiscoveryClient(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());

// Retrieve the matching Service Endpoints via Dynamic Search
Collection<EndpointDiscoveryMetadata> serviceCollection = discoveryClient.Find(criteria).Endpoints;

// Close the Discovery Client
discoveryClient.Close();

// HACK: END -- Process the results of Discovery
```

Note that I'm assuming that this issue is resolved in .NET Framework 4.5 / 4.5.1 - it may not be, but I cannot test that at the moment.

If anyone else has an alternative solution, more elegant or efficient than this, please post it to help others.